# ViewContext.Writer() doesn't exist in ASP.NET MVC 1.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewcontext

I have the following code in an ASP.NET MVC 2 application.

```
internal TextWriter _writer;
// some stuff
_writer = _viewContext.Writer;
_writer.Write(_tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));
```

I tried to move it to MVC 1 and now it doesn't build any more. I'm getting this error:

```
'System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext' does not contain a definition for 'Writer'
```

Can someone point out how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(_viewContext.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream))
{
    textWriter.Write(_tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));
}
```